# Unity - chat not on top of everything

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, chat, unityscript

So, I've been searching ALOT for this and I feel like I've tried pretty much everything, and still I'm coming up short.

The basic idea is to have a chat and also be able to have things in front of that chat window (lets say a draggable menu of sorts).

As a first thing I setup my chat as a GUI element. It works perfect.. word-wrapping and all, but it's always on top of everything else, so this doesn't really work for what I want to do.

The chat box is also scaling depending on your screen resolution.

I think the main issue is going to get it nicely word wrapped when NOT using GUI and I'm just all out of ideas.

Also wanted to state that the "menu" that's going over the chat is going to be containing gameobjects so it's not going to be another GUI element.

Can this even be done?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
But I've had some dealings with Unity3D and IIRC, the GUI's are drawn as the forward-most element on the z-axis - so I don't think you can get actual `gameobjects` in front of them.
Also, I _think_ GUI's are actually rendered in order they are defined in the script, so you would want your top-most GUI to be the last thing in your OnGUI() call.
Lastly, as a side-thought you may want to think about Render-To-Texture as a way of having a GUI containing `gameobjects`: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

Comment: Sounds like the best option for you would be to use the [GUI depth control](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html) just set the depth accordingly to make it come forward and backwards. if you also want to be able to get gameobjects infront of it you have to start using object GUI's nice sample of those would be the NGUI asset

Comment: I actually tried render texture before but it was acting weird because of the alpha I think. Since the window is not going to be see-through it might actually work. I'll give it another go! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use GUI.depth=10 before drawing your chat window, and GUI.depth=5 after everything should appaer on top now.

From the documentation:

Set this to determine ordering when you have different scripts running simultaneously. GUI elements drawn with lower depth values will appear on top of elements with higher values (ie, you can think of the depth as "distance" from the camera).

if you dont want to do this.. determine order of drawing. Whatever gets drawn last is on top.

I understand at this stage it may be hard to do this, but its best to have one OnGUI active in your whole game/app. Having more than one deteriorates performance.

edit: to include scene renders on top of the GUI, you render your scene to a seperate camera (without gui) and have this camera render to texture. this texture can then be used in your gui by using for instance GUI.DrawTexture.

Comment: THe gui.depth only works on other GUI elements. As I mentioned, the overlaying window won't be a GUI element. It's just the way Unity is, GUI gets drawn last, so only way seems to be to use RenderTexture, I haven't got around to trying it yet. It might work for what I want but it also might not.

Comment: Yup, renderTexture. That's what we are going to try next! :) thanks!